# Number of IDs selected

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In the following sql fiddle, how would I change the view to get the desired output?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a737a/1

VIEW

```
select
    sum(dollars) as totalDollars,
    sum(dollars)/count(id) as factor,
    count(id) as numberOfEvents, 
    id as eventID,
    event_date
from
    events
group by
    id,
    event_date
```

Query

```
select
*
from eventStats
where 
event_date between '1/1/2015' and '1/16/2015'
```

desired output

The numberOfevents should = 2 (the actual number of events, not the number of records for each event, determined by the where clause in the query) to properly do the math in the view.

Comment: I guess it should be `fk_id` instead of `id` in the `group by` clause.

Comment: @notulysses thank you, yes that was just an error in my pseudo-sample code.  Corrected!

Answer (score 1):

You can `count` `distinct` `fk_id` without the `group by` clause:

```
select count(distinct fk_id) as number_of_IDs
from [myTable]
where [someCondition]
```

Comment: @ConradFrix yes, and when I do that I still get 2 columns 1/5012 and 1/7008 not, `2`.

Comment: @ConradFrix: I'm really having a bad time understanding the issue. Can you elaborate better, please?

Comment: I'm trying to get the cost per event by dividing sum(dollars) so the query already has a group by clause  `select sum(dollars) / {something that = 2} as cost_of_event, dollars as cost_per_ticket ... where eventDate between '1/1/2015' and 2/1/2015`

Comment: @Travis: Yeah, I understand that, but you shouldn't just replace `count(fk_id)` with `count(distinct fk_id)`, you should replace it with the subquery in my answer.

Comment: The end result is to have this in a view so how would I do that when the where clause would be against the view as a whole?  `from vEventCost where eventDate between '1/1/2015' and '2/1/2015'` I apologize if my original question was foggy.

Comment: @Travis: now it's foggy. What do you mean by _when clause would be against the view as a whole_?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76372/discussion-between-travis-and-notulysses).

Comment: @Travis you should probably add some sample rows to your question. Not only would it help answers, but it would help future visitors with similar problems. using [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) wouldn't hurt

Comment: I don't think this is going to work as view. Do you really need it to be. Other wise you can solve it using COUNT() OVER  [Like so](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a5c6f/14)

Answer (score 0):

Use `distinct` keyword in `count` function:

```
select
    count(distinct fk_id) as number_of_IDs
    ,id
from
    myTable
where
    someCondition
group by
    id
```